# Phone Date in Android?

Tags: android, flash-builder

I am developing a android application, a question, as I can get the date of my phone and show it in a label?.
thank you very much

I’m using flash builder cs5.5

Answer (score 0):

In java, and thus android

```
System.currentTimeInMillis();
```

will return to you a long with a millisecond representation of the time/date that the phone currently thinks it is.

Once you have that you can use a [DateFormater](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) to get it into a string to display it to the user.

**Edit:** I missed the flash tag =(. This is how it can be done with native java. I have no experience with flash on android though, dunno if this will carry over and work under that platform sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that on Android it's different from simple air or flash application. [Date](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) class will help you to do this. Simplest example in Flash Builder and mxml:

```
<s:Label id="label" text="{new Date()}" />
```

and in Flash CS

```
label.text = new Date().toString();
```

And you can format your string like you want, but not in so comfortable way as in Java though :)